# How do you compare two custom objects to each other by a common property?

Tags: c#, compareto

I have a movie object with the following properties

```
public class Movie {
    private string title;
    ...other similar properties...
}
```

How do I implement a CompareTo() class for use in a Binary Tree?

What I've made so far is

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    Movie m1 = (Movie)obj;

    return this.title.CompareTo(m1.title);
}

By trying to use the pre-existing CompareTo() function in string, but it won't work.
```

Comment: what do you mean, by *but it won't work*? according to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_CompareTo_System_String_) must work.

Comment: your code is working as expected.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you implement CompareTo

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var m1 = new Movie() { title = "a1" };
            var m2 = new Movie() { title = "a0" };
            if (m1.CompareTo( m2) == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("equal");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not equal");
            }

        }        

       public class Movie: IComparable
        {
            public string title;

            public int CompareTo(object obj)
            {
                Movie m1 = (Movie)obj;
                return this.title.CompareTo(m1.title);
            }
        }
```